# Shrink a HTML table cell that contains an A tag

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am having a problem shrinking a HTML table cell that contains a single  element. Here's the HTML and CSS (note that the text inside the  has no spaces):

**HTML**

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td class="first-col">Column 1</td>
  <td class="second-col"><a   href="http://example.com">aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeffffffffffff</a></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
width: 100%
}
.first-col {
width: 30%;
}
.second-col {
width: 70%;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/flynam/GwH93/1/

When I make the page's width smaller, the second column does not shrink smaller than the width of the text contained within the  element. Ideally, I want the text to be truncated with ellipsis when the cell should get smaller than the length of the entire line of text.

When I add in this CSS nothing happens:

```
.second-col {
width: auto;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please see here for dynamically changing width of that `td` [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GwH93/4/)

Answer (score 1):

First, add a set `width` to your column. You need to specify a `width` other than `auto` because the browser needs to know when to truncate the text. By setting `auto` to width the text will just expand.

Second, set the display as either `inline-block` or `block`. This is because the [`text-overflow`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui/#text-overflow) property applies only to block containers.

```
.second-col {
    width: 30%;
    display: block; /* or inline-block */
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GwH93/2/)

Comment: Thanks @Harry but again your solution is not quite solving my problem. See my comment above.

Comment: @Frank: I get it. I am not sure if you can handle window resize with just CSS. You might need JS/jQuery to handle that. Let me see if I can find any solutions.